# How to split an equation through text?

Tags: align, split

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\noindent \newline A \textbf{Hamiltonian path} is a directed path that goes through every node exactly once. Consider the problem of testing whether a directed graph contains a Hamiltonian path that connects two specified nodes. Let: 
\begin{multline}
\nonumber HAMPATH = \{\langle G, s, t \rangle| G \text{ is a directed graph with a Hamiltonian path from } s \text{ to } t.\}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

I have the above LaTeX code, and I have looked up, on both TeX SE and Google, how to split equations. I have tried to use `multline` as well as `split` to try and cut the equation so that it fits between the margins. Nothing I have tried so far has worked, so I am at a loss as to what to do.

The final result I am after is the following image, but such that the whole thing sans the things in the `\text{}` environment is formatted as an equation, rather than in plain text:

[image]

Comment: `\noindent \newline `  don't do that:(  but you can have multiple lines in a `multline` by using `\\ `  (and delete the spurious `\end{equation}` that has no `\begin`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

[image]

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
    \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
    \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

    \begin{document}

    A \textbf{Hamiltonian path} is a directed path that goes through
    every node exactly once. Consider the problem of testing whether a
    directed graph contains a Hamiltonian path that connects two
    specified nodes. Let:
    \begin{align*}
    \nonumber \mathit{HAMPATH} &= \{\langle G, s, t \rangle\\
&\quad{} \mid  G \text{ is a directed graph with a Hamiltonian path from }\\
&\qquad s \text{ to } t.\}
    \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```

---

Or judging by comments perhaps you want an inline setting

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

A \textbf{Hamiltonian path} is a directed path that goes through
every node exactly once. Consider the problem of testing whether a
directed graph contains a Hamiltonian path that connects two
specified nodes. Let:
$\mathit{HAMPATH} = \{\langle G, s, t \rangle
\mid  G $ is a directed graph with a Hamiltonian path from 
 $s$ to $t$.$\}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I do this, but make the split within the `\text{}` environment? I tried to move the `&` and the \\ but it just threw a ton of errors.

Comment: @user83024 just close the `\text` do the `\\ ` then have another `\text` on the next line.

Comment: Is it possible to align the bottom line to the left side of the equation? I have it working, but the bottom line is right-aligned. I've tried `flushleft` but it hasn't worked.

Comment: @user83024 you want it to go to the left of the `=` ??

Comment: I want to put it all on the left side of the equation space.

Comment: @user83024 that is so weird:-)

Comment: Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @user83024 i added another setting to my answer

Comment: I have added an image to my answer of what I am looking to do. I did this using `\flushleft`, but this turns the whole thing into plain text and not an equation.

Comment: @user83024 you'd basically get that if you used my second, inline, version but starting a new paragraph after `let:` rather than running it in to the same paragraph (why do you want that though, it is much clearer for the reader if you don't wrap the line to the left of the =)

Comment: The equation is too large to fit onto one line and I think it looks more pleasing to read it like you would a normal line of text.

Comment: @user83024 then set it inline as in my second example, set as a displayed equation but with the "right hand side" to the left of the =  may look more symmetric but will be massively confusing to a reader

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* possibilities, one is to work with `align` and `\MoveEqLeft` that comes with `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
A \textbf{Hamiltonian path} is a directed path that goes through every node exactly once. Consider the problem of testing whether a directed graph contains a Hamiltonian path that connects two specified nodes. Let: 
\begin{align}
 \text{HAMPATH} &= \\
 \MoveEqLeft[4] \{\langle G, s, t \rangle| G \text{ is a directed graph with a Hamiltonian path from } s 
 \text{ to } t.\}\notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get a similar effect to `multline` with a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
A \emph{Hamiltonian path} is a directed path that goes through
every node exactly once. Consider the problem of testing whether
a directed graph contains a Hamiltonian path that connects
two specified nodes. Let
\[
\begin{minipage}{0.8\displaywidth}
  \leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
  \rightskip=0pt plus 1fill
  \parfillskip=0pt plus -1fill
  $\mathrm{HAMPATH} = \{\langle G, s, t \rangle\mid G$
  is a directed graph with \\ a Hamiltonian path from $s$ to $t\}$.
\end{minipage}
\]

\end{document}
```

The settings to `\leftskip`, `\rightskip` and `\parfillskip` ensure left alignment (in the allotted space) in the top line and right alignment in the bottom line.

[image]